# How to make a structured mesh with a hole and extrude it

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I am trying to use the `FEMAddOns` package to make a structured mesh with a hole and then extrude it. As a warm up example this worked nicely.

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
pts1 = Table[
  25. ( Cos[θ]^2 + 1) {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // 
   N, {θ, 0, 2 π, (2 π)/360}]; pts2 = 
 Table[10. {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, 0, 
   2 π, (2 π)/360}];
mesh = StructuredMesh[{pts1, pts2}, {90, 20}];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now I tried my actual problem which has a rectangular boundary.

```
Lx = 100;
Ly = 50;
pts1 = DeleteDuplicates@Join[
    Table[{Lx, L}, {L, 0, Ly, Ly/(2 50)}],
    Table[{L, Ly}, {L, Lx, -Lx, -(Lx/(2 100))}], 
    Table[{-Lx, L}, {L, Ly, -Ly, -(Ly/(2 100))}],
    Table[{L, -Ly}, {L, -Lx, Lx, Lx/(2 100)}],
    Table[{Lx, L}, {L, -Ly, 0, Ly/(2 50)}]
    ];
mesh = StructuredMesh[{pts1, pts2}, {90, 20}];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

This fails with the message

(* StructuredMesh::array: Raster of input points must be a full array of numbers with depth of 4.  *)

Can this be fixed? Can I then extrude the mesh?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Update: New version of FEMAddOns v1.4.2 includes ExtrudeMesh

@user21 updated `FEMAddOns` and `ExtrudeMesh` is included.  Now, you only need to call `FEMAddOns` and don't need to worry about namespace collisions with `MeshTools`.  For completeness, here is the updated workflow to get the latest version of `FEMAddOns` and extend Alex's answer by two lines:

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
(* From Alex Trounev's Answer *)
Lx = 100;
Ly = 50; r[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Lx/Cos[t], 0 <= t <= ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {Ly/Sin[t], 
    ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {-Lx/Cos[t], 
    Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= Pi + ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {-Ly/Sin[t], 
    Pi + ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= 2 Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {Lx/Cos[t], 
    2 Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= 2 Pi}}]; pts1 = 
 Table[r[θ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, 0, 
   2 π, 2 Pi/360}]; pts2 = 
 Table[10. {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, 0, 2 π,
    2 Pi/360}];
mesh2D = StructuredMesh[{pts1, pts2}, {96, 16}];
mesh2D["Wireframe"]
(* Extrude the mesh *)
mesh3D = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, 40, 6];
mesh3D["Wireframe"]
```

## Original Answer

This is an extension of Alex Trounev's answer because I found a potential version problem with `FEMAddOns` package.  Perhaps someone can confirm.

If you download the latest version (v1.4.0) of `FEMAddOns`, you will see that `ExtrudeMesh` appears to be missing.

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
SystemOpen["paclet:FEMAddOns/guide/FEMAddOns"]
```

[image: paclet version]

[image: FEMAddOns Documentation]

A potential workaround is to download MeshTools directly as shown in the following:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["c3m-labs", "MeshTools"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]
(* From Alex Trounev's Answer *)
Lx = 100;
Ly = 50; r[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Lx/Cos[t], 0 <= t <= ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {Ly/Sin[t], 
    ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {-Lx/Cos[t], 
    Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= Pi + ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {-Ly/Sin[t], 
    Pi + ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= 2 Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {Lx/Cos[t], 
    2 Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= 2 Pi}}]; pts1 = 
 Table[r[θ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, 0, 
   2 π, 2 Pi/360}]; pts2 = 
 Table[10. {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, 0, 2 π,
    2 Pi/360}];
mesh2D = StructuredMesh[{pts1, pts2}, {96, 16}];
mesh2D["Wireframe"]
(* Extrude the mesh *)
mesh3D = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, 40, 6];
mesh3D["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Extruded Mesh]

Comment: I have made a new FEMAddOns release that has the `ExtudeMesh` included.

Comment: It looks like `ExtrudeMesh[]` on in my version, but not working without `Needs["MeshTools`"]`. `After that there are two messages coming: `ExtrudeMesh::shdw: Symbol ExtrudeMesh appears in multiple contexts {MeshTools`,Global`}; definitions in context MeshTools` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

StructuredMesh::shdw: Symbol StructuredMesh appears in multiple contexts {MeshTools`,FEMUtils`}; definitions in context MeshTools` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.`

Comment: @user21 Thanks!  I knew you would quickly resolve the issue.  I was confused for a bit why `ExtrudeMesh` was not working, but all is good now.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I saw the same warnings.  There are a lot on namespace collisions when you try to load both `FEMAddOns` and `MeshTools`.  Fortunately, @user21 updated `FEMAddOns` (which technically should include the full `MeshTools`) so that you only need call `FEMAddOns` now.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This has got me going again. Also, thanks user21 for his rapid response..

Answer (score 12):

We can play with numbers to get an ideal mesh. As a stating point you could use this one:

```
Needs["MeshTools`"](*Needs["FEMAddOns`"]*)
Lx = 100;
Ly = 50; r[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Lx/Cos[t], 0 <= t <= ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {Ly/Sin[t], 
    ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {-Lx/Cos[t], 
    Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= Pi + ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {-Ly/Sin[t], 
    Pi + ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= 2 Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx]}, {Lx/Cos[t], 
    2 Pi - ArcTan[Ly/Lx] < t <= 2 Pi}}]; pts1 = 
 Table[r[\[Theta]] {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]} // N, {\[Theta], 0, 
   2 \[Pi], 2 Pi/360}]; pts2 = 
 Table[10. {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]} // N, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi],
    2 Pi/360}];
mesh = StructuredMesh[{pts1, pts2}, {96, 16}];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Thanks Tim Laska for explanation interface with `MeshTools`.   Since I have `MeshTools` installed, I call directly

```
mesh3D = ExtrudeMesh[mesh, 42, 9];
mesh3D["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> EdgeForm[Gray]]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks Alex. What order mesh do you get? Will `ToElementMesh` give a first order or second order?

Comment: @Hugh Just call `mesh["MeshOrder"]` and get answer `1`. In a case of `ToElementMesh` we have order 2 as `Automatic` option and order 1 with option `"MeshOrder"->1` .